# Grep for Weird String

Tags: grep

I was wondering if it's possible to use grep to find all of the text that is in between the following two strings:

```
mutablePath = CGPathCreateMutable();
...
CGPathAddPath(skinMutablePath, NULL, mutablePath);
```

Basically, the first and last lines will always be the same, and there will be a whole bunch of random stuff in between. I would like to count the number of lines that appear between all instances of the first and last line from above.

Is this even possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't do this with `grep`, but you can do it with `awk`.  This is totally untested but should work:

```
awk 'BEGIN { state = 0; count = 0; }
     /^mutablePath = CGPathCreateMutable();$/ { state = 1; }
     /^CGPathAddPath(skinMutablePath, NULL, mutablePath);$/
         { print count; state = 0; count = 0 }
     { if (state) count++; }'  FILE_OF_INTEREST
```

Answer (score 2):

Here's another `awk` solution:

```
awk '/^mutablePath = CGPathCreateMutable\(\);$/ { m=1; c=0 }
     /^CGPathAddPath\(skinMutablePath, NULL, mutablePath\);$/ { print c-1; m=0 }
     m { c++ }'  file
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's an `awk` solution if you have access to that besides `grep`:

```
awk '/^mutablePath = CGPathCreateMutable\(\)\;$/ {in_block=1}
     in_block==1 {count++}  
     /^CGPathAddPath\(skinMutablePath, NULL, mutablePath\)$/ {in_block==0; count--}
     END{print count}' input
```